# python if/else logic explained please

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a really basic if/else logic question for Python. An exercise in the book required me to write a function that takes a list of integers are returns True if the list contains all even numbers and False if it doesn't.

I wrote:

```
list1 = [8,0,-2,4,-6,10]
list2 = [8,0,-1,4,-6,10]
def allEven(list):
    for x in list:
        if x % 2 != 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

This code always returns True. Why is that? Doesn't the code see the -1 during the loop of all the values of the list and returns the False?

```
list1 = [8,0,-2,4,-6,10]
list2 = [8,0,-1,4,-6,10]
def allEven(list):
    for x in list:
        if x % 2 != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

The book gives the answer of this. Why does this work and mine doesn't?

Comment: The code inside the `for` block is supposed to execute multiple times. If you `return True` the first time it executes, the function is finished, and the rest of the loop won't execute. A function only returns once.

Comment: Just to note, you can do this with python's builtin [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function: `return not any(x % 2 for x in values)`. Also, don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: [8.1 The if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)

Comment: `return` what do you think this does?

Answer (score 1):

Pay **close attention** to where that `else` is placed.  Indentation and nesting matters here!

In your first example, it will return `True` on the first element that satisfies your condition because your first `if` check fails.

In your second example, it will return `True` after *all* elements have been iterated through and a return value hasn't been produced.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first function checks the first number only, since it returns something as soon as the for loop starts.

By the way, you can but should not use `list` as an argument or a variable name, since it is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend writing a print statement to output x before both of your return statements.  It will help you understand the flow of the code.

The short answer is that only the first element is being checked by your code, and the function returns True or False based on that value.

In the book solution, any failure causes a return of False, but the loop simply continues otherwise.  Only if all elements are checked without failure does the return True reached.